# What is the time complexity of a for loop that goes up to a constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, big-o

So I have the following code

```
def example(array):
    count = 5
    for _ in range(count):
        array.remove(0)
        array.append(0)
```

What would be the overall time complexity? The for loop itself would be O(1) right? But I'm unsure how the 'array.remove(0)' line will affect the overall time complexity.

Comment: The complexity of `remove()` is O(n). Multiplying by a constant number of iterations doesn't change the overall complexity.

Comment: The overall time complexity would be O(N), since `array.remove(0)` is an O(N) operation on the size of the array

Answer (score 2):

If you take `count` to be a variable, you could say that the complexity of the loop itself is O(count), because it loops `count` times.

In the loop, you are removing an item in `array.remove(0)`, and that has complexity O(N), `N` being the size of the array.

You are also adding a item to the array in `array.append(0)`, which has an *accumulated* complexity of O(1).

In total, the complexity is `O(count*N)`.

On the other hand, if you treat `count` as a constant, that can be factored out, and the complexity becomes `O(N)`.

Comment: Very detail analysis.  Thumb up.

Answer (score 1):

In worst case, `array.remove(0)` will go throught all elements in the array, which is O(n).
So the total complexity is O(count*N), and if count is Constant, it will be same as O(n)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of a loop is the complexity of the loop body multiplied by the number of iterations.

In your example, the complexity of the body is O(n), because that's the complexity of `lsit.remove()`.

Multiplying complexity by a constant has no effect on big-O, so the complexity of the function is still O(n).